# ASP.NET LINQ to Delete Rows

Tags: asp.net, linq, row, delete-row

```
Dim db As New SQLDataContext
Try
    Dim deleteBoatPics = (From boat In db.Photos
                          Where boat.boatid = id)
    db.Photos.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteBoatPics)
    db.SubmitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

I'm getting an error that says:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[WhiteWaterPhotos.Photo]' to type 'WhiteWaterPhotos.Photo'.

I have two separate db.SubmitChanges() because when the button is pressed, I have it delete the records from 1 table, and then the next.

I'm lost, can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Dim db As New SQLDataContext
Try
    Dim deleteBoatPics = (From boat In db.Photos
                          Where boat.boatid = id).take(1).singleordefault
    if not deleteBoatPics is Nothing Then
       db.Photos.DeleteOnSubmit(deleteBoatPics)
       db.SubmitChanges()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Or for a list of elements:

```
Dim db As New SQLDataContext
Try
    Dim deleteBoatPics = (From boat In db.Photos
                          Where boat.boatid = id).ToList()
    if not deleteBoatPics is Nothing Then
       db.Photos.DeleteAllOnSubmit(deleteBoatPics)
       db.SubmitChanges()
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

Comment: Wouldn't that only delete a single row? I want it to remove all rows that contain that id. I also get 'Sequence contains more than one element'

Comment: Second Code Gives This Error ---------
Error 10 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of WhiteWaterPhotos.Photo)' cannot be converted to 'WhiteWaterPhotos.Photo'

Comment: Sorry, the "DeleteOnSubmit" in the second example should have been "DeleteAllOnSubmit"

Comment: You sir, are one heck of a guy. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Dim db As New SQLDataContext
Try
    Dim deleteBoatPics = (From boat In db.Photos
                          Where boat.boatid = id
                          select boat)
    db.Photos.RemoveAll(deleteBoatPics)
    db.SubmitChanges()
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

I don't know vb.net that much but in c# is would have a "select boat" at the end of that query and use 
RemoveAll(...)